# Angular - Number mask for reactive forms that supports min and max values

Tags: angular, angular-validation, input-mask, text-mask

I need to make sure that only numbers are entered in an input text.
I've always used [angular2-text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2/#readme)  but now I also have to make sure that there are limits.A min and max value.
Let's say that the min is 1500 and the max is 16000. If a number less than 1500 is entered then that value is replaced by 1500. If a number greater than 16000 is entered, then that number is replaced by 16000.
I know I could use forms validation, but that's not how the UI has been designed.

[image]

I have covered pretty much what I need with this mask, except the min and max requirements. Do you have any idea how I can get this result?

Comment: you can use the (blur) event to check the value and change according your requeriments

Answer (score 0):

An alternative can be a ViewChild.

0) Put a template reference on the input to be able to reference it.

`<input #myNumInput>`

and in the ts:

`@ViewChild('myNumInput') mynuminput: ElementRef;`

1) register the `keyup` event of the input.

`<input #myNumInput (keyup)="onInputKeyup(#myNumInput.value)">`

2) in the `onInputKeyup` function, check the given value, and if it is out of the ranges you are trying to limit to, adjust it using the viewchild:

```
`if (value < 1500)
    this.mynuminput.value = 1500
 else if (value > 16000)
    this.mynuminput.value = 16000`
```